# How do I print a Dictionary collection in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, dictionary, generic-collections

I'm attempting to print out an array/collection here. I have a class file with the following code to print out the text:

```
//Display All
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ID + "\t" + Product + "\t" + Category + "\t" + Price + "\t" + Stock + "\t" + InBasket);
    }
```

Then, in main I attempt to actually print it out onto screen using this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Farm_Shop> temp in products)
        {
            //display each product to console by using Display method in Farm Shop class
            temp.Display();
        }
```

However I get the following error:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,Farm_Shop_Assignment.Farm_Shop>' 
does not contain a definition for 'Display' and no extension method 'Display'
accepting a first argument of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,Farm_Shop_Assignment.Farm_Shop>' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Here is the actual content I want to print out:

```
products = new Dictionary<int, Farm_Shop>
        {
            { 1, new Farm_Shop(1, "Apple", "Fruit\t", 0.49, 40, 'n') },
            { 2, new Farm_Shop(2, "Orange", "Fruit\t", 0.59, 35, 'n') }
        };
```

From my understanding, this isn't working as I am only sending an array/collection to be printed, and not the int which is meant to come before it, if you know what I mean.

Can someone tell me how I would go about getting it to print correctly.

Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Using such a "Display" side-effect method in a data-oriented class is suspicious. Consider using `string ToString()` or `string GetDisplayText { get; }` or similar (and keeping the display external).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Display()` is a method on `Farm_Shop`. You can't call it directly on an object of type `KeyValuePair<int, Farm_Shop>`. You should do this to access the `Farm_Shop` instance in your [key/value pair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Farm_Shop> temp in products)
    {
        //display each product to console by using Display method in Farm Shop class
        temp.Value.Display();
    }
```

Or loop through the `Values` property, since the key doesn't add much for you (since it came from a property on `Farm_Shop`:

```
foreach (Farm_Shop temp in products.Values)
    {
        //display each product to console by using Display method in Farm Shop class
        temp.Display();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through  each KeyValue pair in the dictionary and gets you the value for each jey

foreach (KeyValuePairtemp in products) //loop through the dictionary
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine(temp.Value);
                        }

Answer (score 0):

It should read something like

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
  product.Value.Display();
}
```

Now you can make your Display method more understandable this way:

```
public Display()
{
   var out=String.Format("{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}",_id,_productName,_categoryName,_this,_that [...]);
   Console.WriteLine(out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the .ToString() method of your object and call that instead of creating a Display method.  Then inside your loop you can do this:

```
foreach(Farm_Shop item in products.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```